# SAS colon format modifier

Tags: sas, formatting, modifier

[image]

What do the numbers in the grey box represent? And what's a simple way of understanding how the colon modifier affects the way sas reads in values?

Comment: Numbers in the grey box are just to help you count characters, it counts characters by 5 to help you find the length/position when needed. 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35 characters.

Comment: Ah that's so simple, thank you. I was reading it as 1,1,2,2,3,3,1,5,0 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on information not provided.  The answer B is the best choice in the sense that you should use the colon modifier when using informats in the INPUT statement to prevent the use of the formatted input mode instead of list input mode.  Otherwise the formatted input could read too many or too few characters and also might leave the cursor in the wrong place for reading the next field.

But if you try to read that data from in-line cards it works fine for those two lines.  That is because in-line data lines are padded to next multiple of 80 bytes.

If you put those lines into a file without any trailing spaces on the lines then the second line fails because there are not 10 characters to read for the last field.  But if you add the TRUNCOVER option (or PAD) to the INFILE statement then it will work.

Try it yourself.  TEST1 and TEST3 work.  TEST2 gets a LOST CARD note.

```
data test1;
  input name $ hired date9. age state $ salary comma10.;
  format hired date9.;
cards;
Donny 5MAR2008 25 FL $43,123.50
Margaret 20FEB2008 43 NC 65,150
;

options parmcards=test;
filename test temp ;
parmcards;
Donny 5MAR2008 25 FL $43,123.50
Margaret 20FEB2008 43 NC 65,150
;

data test2;
  infile test;
  input name $ hired date9. age state $ salary comma10.;
  format hired date9.;
run;

data test3;
  infile test truncover;
  input name $ hired date9. age state $ salary comma10.;
  format hired date9.;
run;
```

With different data the first formatted input can cause trouble also.  For example if the date values used only 2 digits for the year it would throw things off.  So it tries to read FL as the age and then reads the first 8 characters of the salary as the STATE and just blanks as the SALARY.

```
data test1;
  input name $ hired date9. age state $ salary comma10.;
  format hired date9.;
cards;
Donny 5MAR08 25 FL $43,123.50
Margaret 20FEB2008 43 NC 65,150
;
```

Results:

```
Obs    name            hired    age    state       salary

 1     Donny       05MAR2008      .    $43,123.         .
 2     Margaret    20FEB2008     43    NC           65150
```

Comment: Thank you! So if I were to import using infile I could use the truncover option instead of using colon modifiers? If I'm using the cards function is there ever any need for using the colon modifier since there is padding?

Comment: The TRUNOVER really just deals with reading paste the end of the line.  But the formatted input in the middle of the line can also cause issues it just doesn't with this little example. If the HIRED date value had only 2 digits for year it would cause trouble.  Sometimes people like to skip actually defining the lengths of their character variables and use an informat in the INPUT statement to give SAS a hint for how to define the variable. Without the colon that can read right through the delimiters between the values on the line and get the input out of synch.

Comment: I think I have figured it out now thank you! I tried using informats, with and without the colon (on a test data using cards) and noticed SAS didn't know where to seperate the observations into the right columns, unless I added the colon between the variable and the informat.